# Add a class to shortcode generated li item

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a `div` that I have animated to fade in. Now the whole `div` fades in. Great...

Inside this `div` I have a shortcode. This shortcode generates a twitter feed. The twitter feed generates `li` items.

I would like to add a class to one of these `li` items so I can animate it on its own without just animating the whole container.

The questions is, how do I assign a class to the `li` item that's not in the code but generated from a shortcode?

My code is here:

```
<div class="pullout" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="1000">
   <?php echo do_shortcode('[kebo_tweets title="" count="3" style="list" theme="light" offset="false" avatar="off" conversations="false" media="false"]'); ?>
</div>
```

The `data-aos` and `data-aos-duration` control the animation. The short code brings in the twitter feed and generates a list item with the class: `.ktweet`.

Essentially I would like to add the `data-aos` and `data-aos-duration` to the `li`item so I can animate them one by one or apply different animations to them rather than animate the container of the shortcode...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after looking into the source code of this WordPress plugin, you cannot directly add an class through the shortcode.

So the options you have are:

1. Add them with `JS` or `jQuery`
2. Edit the source code itself.

**Option 1 (Recommended)**

*JavaScript*

```
// Get all elements with classname .ktweet
var tweet = document.getElementsByClassName("ktweet");

// Loop through the object
for(var i = 0;i < tweet.length;i++) {
    // Dataset is a set of data stored inside the element as [data-*]
    tweet[i].dataset.aos = "fade-right"; 
    tweet[i].dataset.aosDuration = 1000;
}
```

*jQuery*

```
$(".ktweet").attr("data-aos", "fade-right");
$(".ktweet").attr("data-aos-duration", 1000);
```

**Option 2 (Not recommended)**

- Go into  the plugin folder (kebo-twitter-feed?)
- Search for this line `echo '<div id="' . $widget_id . '" class="kcontainer">';` and just add the attributes or classes there.

Comment: Thanks Red! Perfect and thanks for the in depth explanation! :)

Comment: Thanks, no problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

The php shortcode should generate the `<li>` element prior to page load, so you should just be able to do it via javascript.

```
<div class="pullout" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="1000">
  <?php echo do_shortcode('[kebo_tweets title="" count="3" style="list" theme="light" offset="false" avatar="off" conversations="false" media="false"]'); ?>
</div>

<script>
  document.querySelector('.pullout li').classList.add('MyClass');
</script>
```